# Link in master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

How I can make a link (button) that is located in a master page to redirect to two different url's depending if it is clicked from diferent .aspx pages ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried?

Comment: Expose button NavigateUrl (PostBackUrl) as public property at master page, and set the url depending on loaded page.

Comment: Why do you want it to live in the master page if it's behaviour is not common in the child aspx pages? Or is it common for many pages but needs to differ for these 2? If it is a link you could use javascript in the aspx pages to find the element and change it's href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this in your aspx page load method,

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
          /// Access Master Page control
          LinkButton lnkButton = (LinkButton)this.Master.FindControl("lnkButtonName");
          /// set postback url or whatever
          lnkButton.PostBackUrl = "";
        }
        catch(Execption e)
        {}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set it from the Master's `Page_Init` event handler and use [`HttpContext.CurrentHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.currenthandler.aspx) to get the page reference:

```
protected void Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
    if (page is WebForm1)
        LinkButton1.PostBackUrl = "WebForm2.aspx";
    else if (page is WebForm2)
        LinkButton1.PostBackUrl = "WebForm1.aspx";
    else
        LinkButton1.PostBackUrl = "WebForm3.aspx";
}
```

Comment: @AntonioArredondo: What do you mean? In the case of `WebForm1` the LinkButton redirects to WebForm2.aspx. This is just an example, does it work as expected?

Comment: Hi Tim, what I mean is that regradless in wich .aspx I am if I click the link will redirect me to the same page, I assigned different urls for each WebForm but still , the redirect me to the same page

Comment: This was coded by the guy that I am replacing

String url = Request.Url.ToString().ToUpper(); String toFind; foreach (MenuItem item in menMain.Items) { toFind = item.DataPath.Substring(0, item.DataPath.LastIndexOf('/')).ToUpper(); if (url.Contains(toFind)) { item.Selected = true; lbSearch.PostBackUrl = "~/" + toFind + "/Search/Search.aspx"; lbSetup.PostBackUrl = "~/" + toFind + "/Setup/Setup.aspx"; lbSetup.PostBackUrl = "~/" + toFind + "/SetupLiterature/SetupLiterature.aspx"; break; } }

Comment: @AntonioArredondo: That code looks much more complicated. What should i say, i have tested my code above and it  works for me. So there must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this (untested)...

Inside master page (for this example, it's named siteMaster), add public property:

```
public void SetButtonUrl(string NewUrl)
{
    this.btnMyButton.NavigateURL = NewUrl;
}
```

In the codebehind of your aspx pages, add your desired url in each:

```
((siteMaster)Master).SetButtonUrl("~/someurl");
```